# Using simple jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selector

I want to get a `div` that contains `'xxx'` in its innerHTML.

I could achieve that with the following code :

```
$("div:contains('xxx')")
```

Unfortunately, I can't use this because another plugin already provided me the `div`.

Can I do something like this?!

```
element.contains('xxx')
```

I know I could use filter, but I want to keep it simple.

Can these pseudo-selectors be used as a property with the dot notation?

For example, if I want the last element in the selectors I could use this:

```
 $("div:last")
```

Is there something like this below?

```
$("div").last()
```

I know I could use the code below but I want to keep it simple:

```
$("div").eq($("div").length-1)
```

Any idea how these pseudo-selectors can be used using the dot notation (as properties of the selected elements)?

Comment: `But I cant use this cause another plugin already provided me the "div"` can you explain what you mean by this? If the element's in the DOM then you can select it however you like.

Comment: I am working inside another plugin that gets the elements from an external plugin. I have access only to "element" and I need to use it. I mean, I really need to use "element" in the selector.

Comment: one of JetBrain recommendation is split your "simple pseudo" selector to separate function call. Don`t try to make it harder to read...

Comment: Is it an actual DOM element that you have access to or the jQuery object?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is select the given div like so:

```
div.find(":contains(xxx)")
```

Provided div is a jQuery object otherwise use `$(div)`.

After that just check if the selection contains any elements.
The same goes for the last selector:

```
$("div").find(":last")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how these "pseudo" selectors can be used using the dot notation (as properties of the selected elements)?

Some of them have indeed a method equivalent. [`.last`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) exists. But for those that don't you'd have to use `.filter`. [Here is a list of all jQuery methods](https://api.jquery.com/) where you can look for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) may be what you are looking for.
Try

```
$(element).is(":contains('xxx')");
```

for DOM Element
or

```
element.is(":contains('xxx')");
```

for jQuery object